# Does a vector sort invalidate iterators?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

```
 std::vector<string> names;
 std::vector<string>::iterator start = names.begin();
 std::vector<string>::iterator end = names.end();
 sort (start,end);
 //are my start and end valid at this point?
 //or they do not point to front and tail resp?
```

Comment: I assume that should be `std::vector<string>::iterator start`?

Comment: Even if it is true, the developer that comes after you will waste a day trying to prove this is the root cause for some bug he's fixing...

Comment: @Ben, thanks, sorry copy-paste evil!

Comment: just for the record, the word you're looking for here is "invalidate". :)

Comment: Why the hahaha? I just thought you might want to know because it makes it a lot easier to google in the future. (Iterator invalidation is a term most C++ programmers are familiar with, and while most can probably guess what you mean by an iterator being "spoiled", it probably won't yield as many search results in Google.)

Comment: @jalf `hahaha` because I was struggling with words there. thanks once again, please let me know if you still want me to change the title ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard §23.1/11:

> **Unless otherwise specified** (either explicitly or by defining a function in terms of other functions), invoking
>   a container member function or passing a container as an argument to **a library function shall not invalidate
>   iterators** to, or change the values of, objects within that container.

§25.3 "Sorting and related operations" doesn't specify that iterators will be invalidated, so iterators in the question should stay valid.

Answer (score 16):

They still point to the beginning and end. The values in those slots of the vector have probably changed, but the storage location in which each resides remains the same.

Answer (score 7):

`std::sort` will not invalidate iterators to a vector. The sort template uses the `*` operator on the iterators to access and modify the contents of the vector, and modifying a vector element though an iterator to an element already in the vector will not invalidate any iterators.

In summary,

- your existing iterators will not be invalidated
- however, the elements they point to may have been modified

In addition to the support for the standard provided by Kirill V. Lyadvinsky ([Does a vector sort invalidate iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885482/does-a-vector-sort-change-iterators-if-i-have-start-and-end-before-sort/3885638#3885638)):

- 25/5 "Algorithms library"

> If an algorithm’s Effects section says
>   that a value pointed to by any
>   iterator passed as an argument is
>   modified, then that algorithm has an
>   additional type requirement: The type
>   of that argument shall satisfy the
>   requirements of a mutable iterator
>   (24.1).

- 24.1/4 "Iterator requirements"

> Besides its category, a forward,
>   bidirectional, or random access
>   iterator can also be mutable or
>   constant depending on whether the
>   result of the expression *i behaves as
>   a reference or as a reference to a
>   constant.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` keeps its elements in contiguous memory. `std::sort` takes arguments (iterators) by value and re-arranges the sequence between them. The net result is your local variables `start` and `end` are still pointing to first and one-past-the-last elements of the vector.